# Emacs sometimes freezes from PDFs

Tags: debugging, pdf, pdf-tools

I'm currently using **Emacs 27.1** running on **Ubuntu 21.10**. The problem I have is Emacs stop responding from time to time, but this only occurs when I open a PDF file or while I'm reading PDF books (usually not larger than 35MB in size).

But the freezing doesn't happen instantly, and sometimes it doesn't happen at all.

Here is my `pdf-tools` configuration:

```lisp
(use-package pdf-tools
  :ensure t
  :config
  (pdf-tools-install)
  (setq-default pdf-view-display-size 'fit-width)
  (define-key pdf-view-mode-map (kbd "C-s") 'isearch-forward))
```

I'm not sure why this happens but I suppose it probably has something to do with `pdf-tools` or something related to how Emacs is handling the PDF stuff.